# repeated dropdown menu opens first menu only

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

i use a script which reads members data from database
and put it in a table with a row for every member
each row has a dropdown list with the same class and ID
i used the following codes to open and close dropdown
but the problem is that i can only open the first one

### PHP

> ```
> `
>     <div class="filter-select cf ">
>     <div class="fake-dropdown dropdown-check" id="fake3" style="visibility: visible;">
>     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop3" data-toggle="dropdown" data-autowidth="true">
>     <span class="icn-edit-wheel"></span>
>     <span class="drop-initial"></span>
>     </a>
>     <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" style="top: 25px;">
>     <li><a href="{$baseurl}/edit?id={$posts[i].PID}">Edit</a></li>
>     <li><a target="_blank" href=" {$baseurl}/{$posts[i].seo|stripslashes}/{$posts[i].PID|stripslashes}/{$title}">Preview</a></li>
> ```
>
> `

### script

> `$('#drop3').click(function(e) {
>    $('#fake3').toggleClass("open");
>    e.preventDefault();
>    });`

this is the dropmenu as appear on page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmEV5.jpg

Comment: Because your jquery selector only select id, you should try to select class name.

Comment: Using the same `id` on multiple elements is illegal. try replace them with `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same `id` multiple times. You also can't use a class because it will open all the dropdowns at the same time. An option is to use a JQuery listener and use `this` as start point. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //For toggle class on 'fake-dropdown'
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i tried it and it didn't work
i want to add the class 'open' to the class 'fake-dropdown' in the DIV when i click the class 'dropdown-toggle' in the href

Comment: Ok, then you could use `parent()` instead of `prev()`. I will update my code.

Comment: Sorry, the `prev()` code was just wrong. I misinterpreted the code i think. `parent()` should do the job!

Comment: Thanks for your help Parent() worked with me but i changed a little the code to 
$('.dropdown-toggle').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
}); 

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, add class type, because you can't repeat use same `id` name

**php**

```
<div class="filter-select cf ">
<div class="fake-dropdown dropdown-check fake" id="fake3" style="visibility: visible;">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle drop" id="drop3" data-toggle="dropdown" data-autowidth="true">
<span class="icn-edit-wheel"></span>
<span class="drop-initial"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" style="top: 25px;">
<li><a href="{$baseurl}/edit?id={$posts[i].PID}">Edit</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href=" {$baseurl}/{$posts[i].seo|stripslashes}/{$posts[i].PID|stripslashes}/{$title}">Preview</a></li>
```

**script**

```
$('.drop').click(function(e) {
  $('.fake').toggleClass("open");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**-- edit --**

You can use `closest` to select closest class or use parent to select your element level.

```
$('.drop').click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.fake').toggleClass("open");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks LLL for your help
i tried to add classes instead of IDs but now when i click on one dropdown list then all lists open and all close
so how i can prevent other one from opening ?